# HandlerInterceptor (Spring MVC) equivalent in Play 2.0?

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework

just wondering if there is an equal for HandlerInterceptor  in Play?

"    preHandle() – Called before the handler execution, returns a boolean value, “true” : continue the handler execution chain; “false”, stop the execution chain and return it.
    postHandle() – Called after the handler execution, allow manipulate the ModelAndView object before render it to view page.
    afterCompletion() – Called after the complete request has finished. Seldom use, cant find any use case."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that kind of things in two ways with play. With a "filter" or with a custom "onRouteRequest"-method in your global object.

Read more here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaInterceptors